# How to iterate and replace inner list property in an object with another object property

Tags: java, spring, java-8

I want to replace the `state` String using the origin value on the destination.
Person origin/destination addresses are matched by the identifier `addressId`

**Object structure**

```
Person:
String name
List<Address> address

Address:
String addressId
String city
String state


Person originPerson = new Person();
originPerson.setName("Jon");

List<Address> address = new ArrayList();
Address address = new Address();
address.setAddressId("1");
address.setCity("Malibu");
address.setState("CA");
originPerson.setAddress(address);


Person destinationPerson = new Person();
destinationPerson.setName("Jon");

List<Address> address = new ArrayList();
Address address = new Address();
address.setAddressId("1");
address.setCity("Malibu");
address.setState("MI");
destinationPerson.setAddress(address);
```

**Method**

```
public Person stateReplacer(Person destination, Person origin){
        origin.getAddress().forEach(address -> {
            //CODE
        });
        return destination;
}
```

In the example I want to replace the state MI in the destination using CA from the origin.

I searched for several questions online but couldn't resolve. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I am not quite sure I understand your question, can you clarify a bit on what end result you're expecting?

Comment: Lets say Person(Destination) has got many addresses with different state names. I want to replace all of those state names with the state name with the Person(Origin). I have edited the structure now.

Comment: Why is a second Person object being passed in to stateReplacer just to retrieve the new state? Shouldn't it be something like stateReplacer(Person person, String newState)? That would make the code far easier to implement: just address.setState(newState) where // CODE is.

Comment: The new state is contained within this origin received from external API with other additional messages.

Comment: Can this origin object have 0 or multiple addresses? How do you select the state in that case?

Comment: Always atleast 1 but more than 1 is possible and that would carry unique addressId to match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you described, something like this should work (if you're absolutely certain that the API response cannot have a null or empty origin address and that address IDs will always have a match).

```
public Person stateReplacer(Person origin, Person destination){
    boolean hasOneAddress = origin.getAddress().size() == 1;
    if (hasOneAddress) {
        String newState = origin.getAddress().get(0).getState();
        for (Address address : destination.getAddress()) {
            address.setState(newState);
        }
    }
    else {
        Map<String, String> addressIdStateMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Address address : origin.getAddress()) {
            addressIdStateMap.put(address.addressId, address.state);

        }
        for (Address address : destination.getAddress()) {
            address.setState(addressIdStateMap.get(address.addressId));
        }
    }
    return destination;
}
```